# Bootstrap.min.css navigation collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

i'm currently working on a project right now regarding bootstrap.. I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.
I have a navigation which I need to collapse early around 1200px but when I do so, the links are overflowing like this:

[image]

I dont know what was the reason behind this. But I'm using bootstrap.min.css which I know is different in bootstrap.css alone. Can anyone help me with this ?

And BTW, here's a snippet on what I have already done in my navigation:

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-header {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-left,
.navbar-default .navbar-right {
  float: none !important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
  display: block;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top {
  top: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse.collapse {
  display: none!important;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
  float: none!important;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.navbar-default .collapse.in {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header id="header">
  <nav id="main-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="banner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button>
        <div class="brand-pad"></div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
          <img src="images/logo_white.png" alt="logo" width="210px" height="90px">
        </a>

      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
        <div id="socialicon" class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
          <ul class="navbar-rights ">
            <li class="icon-margin-left icon-margin-right">
              <a class="twitterBtn smGlobalBtn" href="http://twitter.com/"></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="facebookBtn smGlobalBtn" href="http://facebook.com/"></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <br>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pad">
          <li class="scroll active"><a href="#home">HOME</a>
          </li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#features">ABOUT</a>
          </li>
          <li class="scroll"><a class="services" href="#services">OUR SERVICES</a>
          </li>
          <li class="scroll"><a class="collection" href="#portfolio">OUR COLLECTION</a>
          </li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#about">BECOME A MEMBER</a>
          </li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#meet-team">OUR PARTNERS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="scroll"><a href="#pricing">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.container-->
  </nav>
  <!--/nav-->
</header>
<!--/header-->
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to include the css & markup in order for us to help; otherwise we are shooting in the dark.

A fiddle that duplicates the problem would be even better.

Take a look here if you want to know how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have already edited my question sir..

Comment: It was in the triage queue, so it didn't show the updates.

Comment: can you help me sir on this, please I really need to nail this one.

Comment: You should really add the CSS for ALL the customization since it may be relevant: Social area, etc.

Comment: the socia larea is actually not necessary, what I want to happen is just the links to be place the way they should be during collapse.

Comment: Hence why you need to put the rest of your CSS because that Socialization area is the problem or appears to be (no way of knowing without its CSS); if I remove it there aren't any issues.

Comment: here take a look at this: http://www.bootply.com/120604#

Comment: try resizing the browser sir, to more than 768px, because what I need is to early collapse the navigation on the max screen width of 1216px, as you can see in http://www.bootply.com/120604# when you resize to less thaan 768px the links are working fine but not when more than that..

Comment: I edited your question so the Snippet is viewable. Look at that, then decide whether or not to post the rest of your code.